# Python - Decorating a Class Method to test Class Attributes

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to design an interface that tests whether a user is logged in before running certain functions in the class. Rather than:

```
class UserDoesStuff(object):
    def doIfLoggedIn(self):
        if self.checkLogin():
           [...do the stuff...]
```

I was wondering if I could have something like this:

```
def protected(self):
     if not self.checkLogin():
         raise UserLoginError()

@protected
def doIfLoggedIn(self):
    [...do the stuff...]
```

This of course doesn't work, but is there a way to do this using decorators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decorators (the simplest ones, with no extra args) expect functions as input:

```
import functools

def protected(fun):
    @functools.wraps(fun)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.checkLogin():
            raise UserLoginError()
        return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper # this is what replaces the original method

@protected
def doIfLoggedIn(self):
    ...
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much. Will accept as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may take a look at [Django docs on @login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator) and [how they do it](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py).